# 40v oscillating on line when light switch off

Tags: electrical

I was reinstalling a light fixture and it bit me.  I measured the voltage from its hot to neutral and it kept oscillating between 0 and 40V .  It was not phantom voltage I checked.  The light switch (dimmer) feeding this line was off, and there is nothing between the lights and the switch.  What could possibly be going on here and is it dangerous?

Comment: What other equipment was operating in the house or area? only need 1 poor neutral connection...

Comment: everything was on.  please elaborate

Comment: Was the tester you used set to AC or was it set to DC?

Comment: Does the dimmer have a "click" at the end of its range to turn it off, or a separate on-off switch for that matter?

Comment: @DDS AC.  but there was definitely current going through it as per my test with my hand.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel there is a rocker switch with a slide bar with no click. The rocker was off and the slide bar was all the way up.